# Difference between direct download and content-disposition download?

Tags: python, html, django, download

I am a new Django user and please explain the pro's and con's of these 2 types of download options,

**method 1:**

```
<a href="/path/to/download/pleaseanswermyquestion.pdf">Download here</a
```

**method 2:** as a Django view

```
def download(request):
    data = open('/path/to/download/pleaseanswermyquestion.pdf', 'rb')
    bdata = data.read()
    response['content-type'] = "pdf"
    response['content-disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s" %(bdata)
    return response
```

PS: the above python code is wrong but I just want to know the difference between the above 2 concepts of downloading a file from server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is control/security.

With a simple href, the file is generally available for anyone/anything (web spider robots, etc.) to download.

With the second, you can require authentication/login in order to download the file, or serve a different file (perhaps dynamically generated based on the logged in user) or do all kinds of other things. But even with the code as listed - i.e., serving a static file - adding basic security is easy with a download function and not with an href.

FYI, the content-type should probably be `application/pdf`.